# jQuery UI, drag and drop, append into cursor position

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-ui, drag

I'm trying jQuery UI. I have 2 divs: one is my draggable item, and the other is my droppable zone. I'm cloning the draggable item and I append it to my droppable div. My problem is that I need to add the item in the same position where I drop it (where my cursor is), and right now the items are being added to the bottom of my droppable div. Any ideas? (sorry for my broken english).

My JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".block").draggable({ helper: 'clone' }, { grid: [20, 20] }, { revert: "valid" });

    $("#dropZone").droppable({
        accept: ".block",
        drop: function (ev, ui) {
            var droppedTable = $(ui.draggable).clone();
            droppedTable.appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there. You need to fix the syntax for your draggable object:

```
$( ".block" ).draggable({
    helper:'clone',
    grid: [20, 20], 
    revert: "invalid" //assume you want invalid here, not valid
});
```

and use ui.helper to clone the draggable object:

```
$('#dropZone').droppable({
    accept: '.block',
    drop: function(event,ui){
        var droppedTable = $(ui.helper).clone();
        droppedTable.appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mL338128/56/)